# i want to create a history table for table xyz

Tags: database-design, history, audit-trail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [keeping the history of table in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469231/keeping-the-history-of-table-in-java)

Hi,

i want to create a history table for table xyz if user inserted ,updated and deleted in that particular table.i want to store the records in history table like old value,new value,modified date and modified user. any help will truly appreciated.thanks in advance