# keeping the history of table in java

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [keeping the history of table in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469231/keeping-the-history-of-table-in-java)

i need to keep the history of table if user inserted ,updated and deleted from  that table and insert those values into another table and than i need to show up those changes in the UI.
can anybody give me idea how to go through this ..thanks in advance